# Bash profile script order in screen

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, bashrc

I have put an echo in three profile scripts that shows the file name so that I can see the order they run.

When I log in I see.

```
/etc/profile
/etc/profile.d/color-ls
~/.bashrc
/etc/bashrc
$ alias ls
alias ls='ls --ignore=*.pyc --color'
```

Yet when I start a screen session I see

```
~/.bashrc
/etc/bashrc
/etc/profile.d/color-ls
$ alias ls
alias ls='ls --color=tty'
```

The alias I've set up in ~/.bashrc is being overwritten by color-ls but only within screen, is there any round this annoying behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first read [man bash](http://man.cx/bash) (section 'INVOCATION') about when [which file](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files) is actually used.

Your little 'trace' shows you that your `~/.bashrc` **always** sources `/etc/bashrc` which is then calling `color-ls` ... or **not**, depending on code in `/etc/bashrc` as it seems.

So, two ways to solve the problem:

- Check,  under which circumstances `/etc/bashrc` decides to not source `color-ls`.
- Setup your aliases after your `~/.bashrc` processes `/etc/bashrc`.